# Unable to provide the permission to user

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using mq version 9.0,and operating system is linux,we have configured the Active/Passive cluster setup.while application trying to connecting the queue manager getting error JMSWMQ2013 with 2035 error.while we are trying providing the permission to user 'sfms' we are getting error AMQ7026 " A principle or group is invalid".

any one can help on this we unable to providing the permission to user.

also requesting to confirm me for below command,what is the use in which scenarios will use this command.

```
set chlauth(*) type( BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('noboby','*MQADMIN')"
```

please find the below queue manager logs.

```
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2377 -------------------------------------------------------
07/18/2018 03:58:39 AM - Process(23409.32) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(XXXXXX) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.0.0.1) QMgr(QM1)

AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'pfmsadmin'.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'pfmsadmin' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035. If an MQCSP block was used, the User ID in the MQCSP block was ''.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2377 -------------------------------------------------------
07/18/2018 04:16:34 AM - Process(23409.33) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(XXXXXX) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.0.0.1) QMgr(QM1)

AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'pfmsadmin'.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'pfmsadmin' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035. If an MQCSP block was used, the User ID in the MQCSP block was ''.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2377 -------------------------------------------------------
```

@JoshMc: Sorry :) Application User is 'pfmsadmin', we have attached the proper logs please check.

@JoshMc: we have tried given command getting error "id: pfmsadmin: no such user"

@JoshMc: can i create user"pfmsadmin" in local system?

@JoshMc: Yes Josh,my application team is tried to connect my Queueu manager with user and password.can you please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: What user are you specifying in the JMS application?  Is it `mqm`? The block command you provided makes no sense,  where did you see that example?

Comment: I looks like the queue manager is on  unix or linux.   See if the server can resolve the user.  Try on a shell prompt `id -a pfmsadmin`.

Comment: Note you can format fixed width content like i did by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` icon or spacing each line in four spaces.  Also it is probably sufficient to provide only 1 error log entry if they are all the same.

Comment: Note that you can just add a comment unless it is something key to the question like log entries there is no need to add it to the question.  This means that user does not exist on the server where the queue manager is running.   Are you attempting to validate the username and password?   Why are you configuring the JMS application to pass that specific user?

Comment: Can you just add comment down here under the question?   If you have default CONNAUTH configuration then it will try and validate the user and password against the OS so it must exist.

Comment: @praveen, What resolved the issue? Could you please provide details as I'm also getting the same issue? Appreciate any info. on this. If you could provide your sample code and Dockerfile, that would be very helpful.